# Construct a (conditional) independent strong approximation

Tags: probability, statistics, weak-convergence, coupling

It is well known that for the sum of independent r.v., the strong approximation can be achieved using Yurinskii's coupling:

> **Theorem (Yurinskii, 1978).** Let $\xi_{1},\ldots,\xi_{n}$ be independent random variables with $\mathbb{E}\left[\xi_{i}\right]=0$ for each $i$ and $\beta\equiv\sum_{i}^{n}\mathbb{E}\left[\left|\xi_{i}\right|^{3}\right]$ finite. Let $S=\xi_{1}+\ldots+\xi_{n}.$ For each $\delta>0$ there exists a random variable $T$ with a $\mathcal{N}\left(0,\mathrm{Var}\left(S\right)\right)$ distribution such that
> $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|S-T\right|>3\delta\right)\leq C_{0}B\left(1+\left|\log\left(1/B\right)\right|\right)\quad \text{where }B=\beta\delta^{-3},$$
> for some universal constant $C_{0}$.

In above theorem, $\xi_{i}$ are independent and are assumed in $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$. I wonder if it still holds when the independent condition is replaced by conditional independence.

That is, suppose now $\xi_{i}$ are defined in the probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$, where the probability space have the following structure: $\Omega=\Omega^{\left(0\right)}\times\Omega^{\left(1\right)}$, $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}^{\left(0\right)}\otimes\mathcal{F}^{\left(1\right)}$. The only difference is that $\xi_{i}$ are not naturally independent, instead, we have $\xi_{i}$ are *independent conditional on $\mathcal{F}^{\left(0\right)}$*. Does the above Gaussian coupling variable still exist? If so, will the variable be independent of $\mathcal{F}^{\left(0\right)}$?

Any comments / counter examples / hints on proof are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: So, do you want the coupling for the random variables $(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)|\mathcal{F}_0$ or $(\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)$?

Comment: @SumanChakraborty The final result is of $S$ I think. But for the former one if we can show the coupling of $S\vert \mathcal{F}_{0}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{0}$, it should be a coupling of $S$ as well, right?

Comment: I am not entirely sure. You are right that if you can show that the coupling of $S|\mathcal{F_0}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F_0}$, then you are done. But the problem with strong approximation (as far as I understand) is that the coupling might live in an entirely different probability space. In that case, the coupling, say $S'$ and $\mathcal{F_0}$ are in different spaces altogether.

Comment: @SumanChakraborty Yes, that's the problem. So in this question I care more about the independence property. Once we have the independence, everything is done. We can then construct a larger space using product measure and put the variables together, with the coupling still being Gaussian on that space.